# Unable to get @login_required decorator to work

Tags: python, flask

I can not get my app to accept logged in user. I don't get errors and there is no logic for password implemented yet.
I am following the steps from [readthedocs](https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#flask.ext.login.login_user) but am unable to work it out.

**Expected:**
User logs in and gets to visit page requiring log in.

**Actual:**
User logs in but gets redirected to log in page when attempting to visit a page requiring log in.

What have I missed in my code?

EDIT: My `load_user(user_id)` method always returns none, why is that?

EDIT2: I have come to realize that my user object is only created in the login method. What changes do I have to make in the code to make user reachable from other methods?

```py
    from flask import Flask, render_template, request, redirect, session
    from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, login_user, UserMixin, logout_user
    from werkzeug.security import generate_password_hash
    
    
    app = Flask(__name__)
    
    app.secret_key = "Redacted"
    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.init_app(app)
    
    
    class User:
        def __init__(self, name):
            self.name = name
    
        def is_authenticated(self):
            return True
    
        def is_active(self):
            return True
    
        def is_anonymous(self):
            return False
    
        def get_id(self):
            return unicode(1)
    
    
    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        try:
            return User.get_id(user_id)
        except:
            return None
    
    
    login_manager.login_view = 'login'
    
    
    @app.route('/')
    @login_required
    def index():
        return render_template('index.html')
    
    
    @app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
    def login():
        if request.method == "POST":
            name = request.form.get("username")
            password = generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password"))
            if not name:
                print("debug: did not recieve a name")
            user = User(name)
            login_user(user)
            return redirect('/')
        else:
            return render_template('login.html')
    
    
    @app.route('/logout', methods=['GET'])
    @login_required
    def logout():
        logout_user()
        return redirect('/')
    
    
    if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some differences between the docs and your code.

Your code:

```
return User.get_id(user_id)
```

does not return an instance of a user but an ID. You may have other errors too.
Then, in case of exception, you return None:

```
    except:
        return None
```

but the exception otherwise goes unnoticed, which is not a good thing. I would suggest that you raise the exception, at least in dev mode, or at a minimum log the message somewhere. If you ignore the exceptions that occur, this will only make the program more difficult to debug.

Personally I use something like:

```
if current_user.is_authenticated:
    return redirect(url_for('index'))

form = LoginForm()

if form.validate_on_submit():
    user = User.query.filter_by(username=form.username.data).first()
    if user is None or not user.check_password(form.password.data):
        errors.append('Invalid username or password')
        # log failure
        return redirect(url_for('cp_bp.login'))
    else:
        login_user(user)
```

The idea is to locate the user by name (with the ORM FlaskAlchemy), then check the password, and log the user in.

You probably know it but your code is not yet complete. You are logging the user in without checking that the password is correct.

When you have a valid session in Flask, then you can use `current_user` to refer to the logged-in user.

You import it like this (along with other needed methods):

```
from flask_login import LoginManager, login_required, current_user, login_user, logout_user
```

Then you can use properties like: `current_user.name` or `current_user.id` elsewhere in your code, depending on your personal implementation of the User model.

Answer (score 0):

You are using concepts from a factory function in your application yet you have not really defined one.

Solution 1: No factory function

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager

app = Flask(__name__)

login_manager = LoginManager(app)  # < ---- add (app)
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

# the rest of your code remains
# ...

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```

Solution 2: Using a factory function

```py
from flask import Flask
from flask_login import LoginManager
from config import Config

login_manager = LoginManager()
login_manager.login_view = 'login'

def create_app(config_class=Config):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(config_class)

    login_manager.init_app(app)

return app

from app import models # add any other model used

# the rest of your code remains
# ...

@login_manager.user_loader
def load_user(id):
    return User.query.get(int(id))
```